# Websphere v8.0.0.6 WASX7017E, ADMA0209E Application exception while Deployment of EJB 2.0 EAR

Tags: deployment, ear, ejb-2.x, websphere-8

I have the following problem with WebSphere 8.0.0.6 and no solution is found on the web. I hope anyone can help with this and this will help someone else with this problem.

## Error Description:

### Error #1 (while installing application):

```
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file /tmp/wsant3816346180883063201jacl;
exception information:com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException
```

### Following Error:

```
ADMA0209E: Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) module ServerEJB.jar contains the following 
container-managed persistence (CMP) or bean-managed persistence (BMP) : 
... (list of all entities)
```

### Explanation:

I generate an EAR with an EJB 2.0 component/project. Up to now I have deployed this EAR within WAS 6.1 successfully, but with WAS 8 it doesn't deploy anymore.

I have the necessary bind-ejbjar.xmi, even in the new format - converted with the script from IBM.

## Questions:

WAS 8 still seems to know that there exists a EJB 3 component  in the EAR - the question is WHY?

What is the minimum requirement for a EAR/EJB-Module to deploy in WAS 8 - there must be big changes?

Are there more bind-files to be included?

Thanks for help

UPDATE: 
So obviously there are prerequisites to declare a package as EJB2.x.
See IBM-HelpCenter:

[IBM WebSphere info for developers DE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/rejb_consid.html&lang=de)

But I fullfill all of this two prerequisites.

How do I have to package the jar for Websphere 8 to make it acceptable as an EJB2.x?

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc%2Fae%2Frejb_consid.html&lang%3Dde

Comment: Did you upgrade the ejb-jar.xml to be version="3.0" or version="3.1"?  If yes, BMP/CMP are not supported in those module versions.  If no, what do you mean by "bind-ejbjar.xmi, even in the new format"?  The new ibm-ejb-jar-bnd/ext.xml (vs .xmi) is only used for 3.0+ modules.

Comment: Sorry, don't think about "the new format" ... you are right, its only for 3.x ejb modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was achieved by **upgrading to version 2.1** ejb, because there the "version" attribute is allowed and this is required by WebSphere to recognize a non-EJB 3.0 version.

This means that an EJB 2.0 version can not work, since the above tag is not allowed in the ejb-jar_2_0.dtd. Maybe a 
     `<cmp-version>2.x</cmp-version>`
could help here, but I didn't tested it.

The conversion of the header of ejbjar.xml brought success:

from 2.0 (ejb-jar_2_0.dtd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN" 
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">
    <!-- EJB-jar file declaration -->
<ejb-jar id="EJBJar" version="2.0">
    <display-name>Overall Bean Definition</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
    <entity id="Dcnotetext">
    ...
```

to 2.1 (ejb-jar_2_1.xsd - you need namespaces! ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar id="EJBJar"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
  version="2.1"    
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd">
    <!-- EJB-jar file declaration -->
    <display-name>Overall Bean Definition</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
    <entity id="Dcnotetext">
     ...
```

No further changes to XMI or XML files were necessary!

Thanks for help!